# Unhandled Exception: type '_TypeError' is not a subtype of type 'String'

Tags: flutter, dart

I am getting this error on my flutter app.

Unhandled Exception: type '_TypeError' is not a subtype of type 'String'

```
List<Cars> cars = docs.map((e){
    return Car(name: e.data["name"])
});
```

Comment: Why do you dislike the question? This is a valid error that is kinda confusing and I provided the answer so people can find this if they have the same error

Answer (score 2):

**The answer is:** You need to use **.toList()** on the map function

```
List<Cars> cars = docs.map((e){
    return Car(name: e.data["name"])
}).toList();
```

Hope this helps someone who receives the same weird error